# How to change language in the website using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am beginner in JavaScript and bootstrap, i have added the navbar but i want to change the navbar titles language (Home,About us,Our Service,Contact us) by clicking the button at the top of navbar. Below is the bootstrap code.

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Spanish</button>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <img src="images/logo.png" width="60" height="55" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="" loading="lazy">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto text-center">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="aboutus.html">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="ourservices.html">Our Services</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="fire" href="http://eatxact.com/#">Login</a>
        </div> </nav>
```

Comment: Use [DOM methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents) to change the `lang` attribute and replace each text node with your translations. (This sort of problem is usually easier to solve with a template language (or SPA framework like React) and an i18n library)

Answer (score 1):

You can create locale for some language, like 'en' or 'uk' and add it to the url of the website and simply redirect to the correct localizated page by clicking on the button.

But it would reload the page. If you want not to do it, Siddharth S.`s answer is the best choice

Comment: I saw some examples there are using `<p id="test">Hello</p>` but problem is i have nested class id's which is mentioned in the code

Comment: @mohammed-nabil, maybe I don`t know someting? 
"Nested class id`s", could you tell me more about this, please?